# Problemas con serializacion

Tags: java, jframe, serialización

Estoy realizando un proyecto de un parqueadero el cual registra clientes,el vehículo de cada uno de ellos,la cantidad de horas que van a durar,calculo el precio dependiendo del vehículo, etc... Hasta hay todo bien,tengo que ir aumentando por poner un ejemplo la suma total de lo que recibió el parqueadero por cada vehículo, esto lo voy haciendo en una clase ( Informes ) con atributos static, y la ventana de *JFrame* me los muestra como debe ser, el problema es que al cerrar el programa y volverlo a abrir la clase Informes tiene todos los valores por defecto que serian de 0 y obviamente la Ventana *JFrame* tambien me muestra todo en 0.

PD: El programa lee el serializable cuando se inicia y lo guarda cuando se cierra.

**Clase Informes**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Informes implements Serializable{  

private static double sdinerot = 0, sdineroTA = 0, sdineroTB = 0, sdineroTC = 0, sdinerocarro = 0,
        sdinerocamioneta = 0, sdinerobus = 0, sdineromoto = 0, pClienteA = 0, pClienteB = 0, pClienteC = 0;
private static int tCA = 0, tCB = 0, tCC = 0;  


public double getSdinerot() {
    return sdinerot;
}

public void setSdinerot(double total) {
    sdinerot = sdinerot + total;

}

public double getSdineroTA() {
    return sdineroTA;
}

public void setSdineroTA(double sdineroTA) {
    this.sdineroTA = this.sdineroTA + sdineroTA;


}

public double getSdineroTB() {
    return sdineroTB;
}

public void setSdineroTB(double sdineroTB) {
    this.sdineroTB = this.sdineroTB + sdineroTB;


}

public double getSdineroTC() {
    return sdineroTC;
}

public void setSdineroTC(double sdineroTC) {
    this.sdineroTC = this.sdineroTC + sdineroTC;


}

public int gettCA() {
    return tCA;
}

public void setcCA() {
    tCA++;


}

public int gettCB() {
    return tCB;
}

public void setcCB() {
    tCB++;


}

public int gettCC() {
    return tCC;
}

public void setcCC() {
    tCC++;


}

public double getSdinerocarro() {
    return sdinerocarro;
}

public void setSdinerocarro(double sdinerocarro) {
    this.sdinerocarro = this.sdinerocarro + sdinerocarro;


}

public double getSdinerocamioneta() {
    return sdinerocamioneta;
}

public void setSdinerocamioneta(double sdinerocamioneta) {
    this.sdinerocamioneta = this.sdinerocamioneta + sdinerocamioneta;


}

public double getSdinerobus() {
    return sdinerobus;
}

public void setSdinerobus(double sdinerobus) {
    this.sdinerobus = this.sdinerobus + sdinerobus;


}

public double getSdineromoto() {
    return sdineromoto;
}

public void setSdineromoto(double sdineromoto) {
    this.sdineromoto = this.sdineromoto + sdineromoto;


}

public void setPromedioClienteA() {
    if (tCA == 0) {
        pClienteA = 0;
    } else {
        pClienteA = (sdineroTA / tCA);
    }

}

public void setPromedioClienteB() {
    if (tCB == 0) {
        pClienteB = 0;
    } else {
        pClienteB = (sdineroTB / tCB);
    }


}

public void setPromedioClienteC() {
    if (tCC == 0) {
        pClienteC = 0;
    } else {
        pClienteC = (sdineroTC / tCC);
    }


}

public static double getPromedioClienteA() {
    return pClienteA;
}

public static double getPromedioClienteB() {
    return pClienteB;
}

public static double getPromedioClienteC() {
    return pClienteC;
}
```

}

**Clase donde guardo lo serializado**

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Vector;

public class DatosGenerales {

public static Vector<Clientes> vector = new Vector<Clientes>();

public static void guardarSerializadoClientes() {
    try {
        File miFile = new File("DatosClientes.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream datos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(miFile));
        datos.writeObject(DatosGenerales.vector);
        datos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void leerSerializadoClientes() {
    ObjectInputStream datos;
    File miFile = new File("DatosClientes.txt");
    try {
        datos = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(miFile));
        DatosGenerales.vector = (Vector) datos.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void guardarSerializadoInformes() {
    Informes informes = new Informes();
    try {
        File miFile = new File("Informes.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream datos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(miFile));
        datos.writeObject(informes);
        datos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void leerSerializadoInformes() {
    Informes informes = new Informes();

    ObjectInputStream datos;
    File miFile = new File("Informes.txt");
    try {
        datos = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(miFile));
        informes = (Informes) datos.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

**Clase Clientes**

```
public class Clientes implements Serializable {

private String nombre = "", apellido = "", placa = "", sexo = "";
private double identificacion = 0, telefono = 0, total = 0;
private int horas = 0, tipovehiculo = 0, tipocliente = 0, edad = 0;

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public String getPlaca() {
    return placa;
}

public void setPlaca(String placa) {
    this.placa = placa;
}

public double getIdentificacion() {
    return identificacion;
}

public void setIdentificacion(double identificacion) {
    this.identificacion = identificacion;
}

public double getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(double telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public double getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public int getHoras() {
    return horas;
}

public void setHoras(int horas) {
    this.horas = horas;
}

public int getTipovehiculo() {
    return tipovehiculo;
}

public void setTipovehiculo(int tipovehiculo) {
    this.tipovehiculo = tipovehiculo;
}

public int getTipocliente() {
    return tipocliente;
}

public void setTipocliente(int tipocliente) {
    this.tipocliente = tipocliente;
}


public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

public String getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public void setSexo(String sexo) {
    this.sexo = sexo;
}

//Calcular el total segun el tipo de vehiculo
public void setCalcular() {

    Vehiculos vehiculos = new Vehiculos();
    Informes informes = new Informes();
    switch (tipovehiculo) {
        case 1:
            vehiculos.setCarro(tipocliente, horas,identificacion);
            total = vehiculos.getTotal(); //Establece el total del cliente
            informes.setSdinerocarro(total);//Suma promedio total para los carros
            break;
        case 2:
            vehiculos.setCamioneta(tipocliente, horas,identificacion);
            total = vehiculos.getTotal();//Establece el total del cliente
            informes.setSdinerocamioneta(total);//Suma promedio total para las camionetas
            break;
        case 3:
            vehiculos.setBus(tipocliente, horas,identificacion);
            total = vehiculos.getTotal();//Establece el total del cliente
            informes.setSdinerobus(total);//Suma promedio total para los buses
            break;
        case 4:
            vehiculos.setMoto(tipocliente, horas,identificacion);
            total = vehiculos.getTotal();//Establece el total del cliente
            informes.setSdineromoto(total);//Suma promedio total para las motos
            break;
    }

    informes.setSdinerot(total); //Sumar los totales de todos los clientes       

}
```

}

**Clase Vehiculos**

```
public class Vehiculos {

private double total = 0;
Informes informes = new Informes();

public void setCarro(int tipocliente, int horas, double id) {
    switch (tipocliente) {  //Calcular el total segun el tipo de cliente
        case 1:
            total = ((3500 * horas) - ((3500 * horas) * 0.25));

            //Verificamos si el cliente existe para no tener que sumar el tipo de cliente
            int s = getVerificar(id);
            if (s == 0) {//Si el cliente no existe
                informes.setcCA();
            }

            informes.setSdineroTA(total);
            informes.setPromedioClienteA();
            break;
        case 2:
            total = ((3500 * horas) - ((3500 * horas) * 0.15));

            //Verificamos si el cliente existe para no tener que sumar el tipo de cliente
            int j = getVerificar(id);
            if (j == 0) {//Si el cliente no existe
                informes.setcCB();
            }

            informes.setSdineroTB(total);
            informes.setPromedioClienteB();
            break;
        case 3:
            total = ((3500 * horas));

            //Verificamos si el cliente existe para no tener que sumar el tipo de cliente
            int k = getVerificar(id);
            if (k == 0) {//Si el cliente no existe
                informes.setcCC();
            }

            informes.setSdineroTC(total);
            informes.setPromedioClienteC();
            break;
    }

}

public void setCamioneta(int tipocliente, int horas, double id) {
    switch (tipocliente) {   //Calcular el total segun el tipo de cliente
        case 1:
            total = ((5000 * horas) - ((5000 * horas) * 0.25));

            //Verificamos si el cliente existe para no tener que sumar el tipo de cliente
            int s = getVerificar(id);
            if (s == 0) {//Si el cliente no existe
                informes.setcCA();
            }

            informes.setSdineroTA(total);
            informes.setPromedioClienteA();
            break;
        case 2:
            total = ((5000 * horas) - ((5000 * horas) * 0.15));

            //Verificamos si el cliente existe para no tener que sumar el tipo de cliente
            int j = getVerificar(id);
            if (j == 0) {//Si el cliente no existe
                informes.setcCB();
            }

            informes.setSdineroTB(total);
            informes.setPromedioClienteB();
            break;
        case 3:
            total = ((5000 * horas));

            //Verificamos si el cliente existe para no tener que sumar el tipo de cliente
            int k = getVerificar(id);
            if (k == 0) {//Si el cliente no existe
                informes.setcCC();
            }

            informes.setSdineroTC(total);
            informes.setPromedioClienteC();
            break;
    }
}

public void setBus(int tipocliente, int horas, double id) {
    switch (tipocliente) {  //Calcular el total segun el tipo de cliente
        case 1:
            total = ((6500 * horas) - ((6500 * horas) * 0.25));

            //Verificamos si el cliente existe para no tener que sumar el tipo de cliente
            int s = getVerificar(id);
            if (s == 0) {//Si el cliente no existe
                informes.setcCA();
            }

            informes.setSdineroTA(total);
            informes.setPromedioClienteA();
            break;
        case 2:
            total = ((6500 * horas) - ((6500 * horas) * 0.15));

            //Verificamos si el cliente existe para no tener que sumar el tipo de cliente
            int j = getVerificar(id);
            if (j == 0) {//Si el cliente no existe
                informes.setcCB();
            }

            informes.setSdineroTB(total);
            informes.setPromedioClienteB();
            break;
        case 3:
            total = ((6500 * horas));

            //Verificamos si el cliente existe para no tener que sumar el tipo de cliente
            int k = getVerificar(id);
            if (k == 0) {//Si el cliente no existe
                informes.setcCC();
            }

            informes.setSdineroTC(total);
            informes.setPromedioClienteC();
            break;
    }
}

public void setMoto(int tipocliente, int horas, double id) {
    switch (tipocliente) {  //Calcular el total segun el tipo de cliente
        case 1:
            total = ((3000 * horas) - ((3000 * horas) * 0.25));

            //Verificamos si el cliente existe para no tener que sumar el tipo de cliente
            int s = getVerificar(id);
            if (s == 0) {//Si el cliente no existe
                informes.setcCA();
            }

            informes.setSdineroTA(total);
            informes.setPromedioClienteA();
            break;
        case 2:
            total = ((3000 * horas) - ((3000 * horas) * 0.15));

            //Verificamos si el cliente existe para no tener que sumar el tipo de cliente
            int j = getVerificar(id);
            if (j == 0) {//Si el cliente no existe
                informes.setcCB();
            }

            informes.setSdineroTB(total);
            informes.setPromedioClienteB();
            break;
        case 3:
            total = ((3000 * horas));

            //Verificamos si el cliente existe para no tener que sumar el tipo de cliente
            int k = getVerificar(id);
            if (k == 0) {//Si el cliente no existe
                informes.setcCC();
            }

            informes.setSdineroTC(total);
            informes.setPromedioClienteC();
            break;
    }
}

public double getTotal() {
    return total;
}

private int getVerificar(double id) {
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < DatosGenerales.vector.size(); i++) {
        Clientes c = DatosGenerales.vector.get(i);
        if (c.getIdentificacion() == id) {
            a = 1;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (a == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

En tu clase Informes, las variables estáticas (static) no se van a serializar con su valor si hubiera cambiado. Se van a serializar con el valor del constructor o predefinido, como lo tienes.

El esquema de serialización de java no serializa objetos estáticos, ni tampoco los definidos como transient.

Si quieres serializar los valores de tus variables de tu clase Informe, necesitas definirlas como variables de clase, o sea "no estáticas".

Comment: Pero si las defino como no estaticas los valores no se van a estar modificando como lo hacen siendo estaticas, osea retomando el ejemplo que di la suma por cada vehiculo no va a estar sumandose constantemente

Comment: No entiendo porque dices que no se van a modificar los valores si no son estáticas. Una variable estática lo que significa es que su valor es el mismo para cualquier instancia de la clase que los encapsula. Cuantas instancias de tu clase Informes vas a tener?

Comment: Mira he añadido a mi pregunta el codigo de la clase clientes y la clase vehículos la clase clientes esta guardandose en un ArrayList porque no se cuantos clientes puedan entrar al parquedaero, entonces cuando registro al cliente mando a llamar al metodo calcular para que me de el precio total a pagar del cliente, en la clase vehiculos voy a estar llamando los metodos de los tipos de clientes e ir sumandolos en la clase informes, entonces por eso es que nesecito tenerlos estaticos para poder estar aumentando el valor de cada atributo de la clase informes